# create a record with default values

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

im wondering how to create a record with default values, for example if I create an employee and I would like to create password automatically as "default" without displaying input field, i tried this 
`echo $this->Form->input('password',array('value'=>'default'));` 
but password field is still displayed when I create employees, please post your thoughts, really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not show a field, you use a hidden field:

```
$this->Form->hidden('password',array('value'=>'default'));
```

To show a field, but give it a default value, I'm pretty sure this works:

```
$this->Form->hidden('password',array('default'=>'my_value'));
```

With regards to posting my thoughts, my thoughts are that creating a password with a default value is very insecure, and defeats the purpose of having one at all. What you should do is set a account_confirmation_token field or similar. Then, when you create an account, you automatically set that to a random string, and send a link to the employee, containing that string.

Then, that string is used to identify the employee and allow them to set their password for the first time. Prior to setting their password for the first time, they should not be able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

It is very insecure to create it in a hidden field.

Try to do this.. in your model you can do

Delete the field of your code and:

```
public function beforeSave() 
{
     $this->data[$this->name]["password"] => "bla bla bla";
     return true;
}
```

Comment: It's not necessarily insecure to create a hidden field - it depends on the situation.

Comment: Also if you use CakePHP's security component, then having a hidden field should be fine; users should not be able to get away with modifying them.